# Is there a way to confirm and decompress files that I suspect are compressed with a very early format of PKZIP?

Tags: file-format, encryption, decompress

I have a very large number of files (tens of thousands) who's binary all begins with 0x00 0x06.  They do not open with 7-ZIP.  I notice also that all Office files seem to share the same next 32 bytes.

```
A03D8B002E542C0DE10000C41EF0016000007FFF120030483E09F883AD3C0362
```

It is a very old format, so I cannot find a decompression program, and do not even know how to confirm that it is the indeed an old PKZIP format.

The compressed file is indeed compressed by about 50%.

Comment: Do the file contents start with `PK`?

Comment: No, with 0x00 0x06

Comment: Do you have the application that created those files ? Can you share one of them ? There are plenty of pkzip-like compression programs out there, so we would need more context to actually provide something meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, creating a fake file using

```
perl -e 'print "\x00\x06\xde\xad\xbe\xef";' > foo
```

and running `file foo` yields

```
foo: TTComp archive data
```

Then it's easy: http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/TTComp_archive which says that it used the early [PKWARE "implode" algorithm](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/PKWARE_DCL_Implode)

> DCL Implode is not the same format as ZIP's old "implode" compression
>   method (#6). It is unfortunate that there are two formats named
>   "implode"  associated with the same company. It can be used in ZIP, as
>   compression  method #10, but support for this is limited.
>
> The terms "blast" and "explode" are sometimes used in association with
>   this format.

There are decoders for it, for example [this one](https://github.com/JoshVarga/blast) written in Go.

Answer (score 1):

I would first confirm the file format. Without the entire file this is difficult. Recommend you run the application through a signature based identification program to identify matches.

For example TridNet which detects over 12,000 different file types:

[TriDNet](http://mark0.net/soft-tridscan-e.html)
[Online TriDNet](http://mark0.net/onlinetrid.html)

Based on the file bytes provided (which may not be sufficient to determine) expect file type is TTComp archive compressed (bin-4K).

If TTComp format, the first byte 0x0 indicates binary file; 0x06 indicates a 4096 byte dictionary which was the most common size dictionary for this file type. 
These files can be decompressed with [TTDecomp](http://www.exelana.com/techie/c/ttdecomp.html)